# Returning RDF from Controller Action - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, rdf, mvccontrib

I have a controller action that returns a RDF document as XML to the browser. The browser complains that the document cannot be displayed:

> The namespace prefix is not allowed to start with the reserved string "xml". Error processing resource

I was attempting to use MCVContrib's XMLResult object to write the document out to the response stream. How can I have this document displayed correctly to the browser? Do I have to resort to writing a plain string?

```
 public ActionResult Content(string id, string version, string localization)
    {
        IDocumentRequest request = new ResourceRequest()
                                       {
                                           Id = id,
                                           Localization = Localization.GetByName(localization),
                                           Version = version
                                       };

        XmlDocument doc = _kbModel.GetContent(request);

        return new XmlResult(doc);
    }
```

Comment: Are you looking for a way to show ActiveReports reports in MVC?

Comment: It clearly states that the namespace contains 'xml' term (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/262585).. just review your source code in GetContent method and replace that prefix with something else.

Comment: The RDF is correctly formed and displays as expected in FF.

Answer (score 0):

RDF has a different MIME type thank just XML. XMLResult will set the MIME type to "application/xml" and what is needed by RDF is "application/rdf+xml". You need to set this manual or you can create your own ActionResult that sets it.

SEE: http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-syntax-grammar/#section-MIME-Type

Answer (score 0):

You have an **`xml`** `namespace (as 'xmlns:xml="..."')` at the root of your returned document.

**OR**

You are using an old `Microsoft XML (MSXML)` parser equal to `Microsoft XML Core Services version 4.0` or lower. **Update** to the [last version of MSXML](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19662).

**Reason**: You are using one/some of Microsoft XML (MSXML) keywords in your namespace prefixes in the returned XML document, i.e `xml`,

For example you have a namespace like `xmlMyProject` in returned xml document. Note that `xml` capitalization doesn't matter, i.e. `XMLMyProject`, `XmlMyProject`...